# I want the directory to be replaced with a space " ", how can I do it?

Tags: c#

When MultiVal is null, I want it to be replaced by a space " ", how can I do it?

```
var selectedComponents=string.Join(',', MultiVal);
sb.Replace("{components}",selectedComponents);
```

Comment: Perhaps `var selectedComponents=string.Join(',', MultiVal??" ");`, See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator

Answer (score 1):

If I understood correctly

```
var selectedComponents = MultiVal == null ? " " : string.Join(',', MultiVal);
sb.Replace("{components}", selectedComponents);
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do something like:

```
var selectedComponents = string.Join(',', MultiVal ?? "");
sb.Replace("{components}",selectedComponents);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var selectedComponents = string.Join(',', MultiVal ?? new string[] {" "});
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope you are looking for something like this. If MultiVal is **not null** you can place another string where it says string.Empty:

```
var selectedComponents = string.Join(",", MultiVal == null? " " : string.Empty);
```

Or you can just simply check if MultiVal is null:

```
    if (MultiVal == null)
    {
        selectedComponents = string.Join(",", " ");
    }
```